# PropertyGrid is not displayed properly with .NET 5

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-core, propertygrid

I have a winform project compiled to .NET 4.7.2.
It has a PropertyGrid element on the main form and it is displayed well.
After migrating to .NET 5, it does not look as expected:

[image]

Some text appears on top of the control and to view the value of any property - one has to click on it.

Comment: That was really a silly mishap. Go back to 5.0.3 and it's ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a (huge) regression with .NET 5.0.4. See here:

"The default value is not displayed in the correct position after setting SelectedObject property for PropertyGird control"

https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/4593

It will be fixed in 5.0.5.

Comment: Indeed the new version 5.0.5 was released and this issue was fixed.